# Colaborative map-editing tool for Paranoia games

Tags: tools, tool-recommendation, map-making, paranoia

I am running a multi-group paranoia with a couple of friends.
We are usually playing with 3 Gamemasters and 5 people per group at the same time in the same realm.

We are looking for a colaborate map-tool (webbased) where we can add items to the world that each gamemaster can see them in realtime. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Roll20](https://www.roll20.net/) supports running a game with multiple game masters.  The caveat, as I understand it, is that all the players will be on the same page, while the game masters can work on any page.  The creator of the game will need to be a subscriber to Roll20 if you need any subscriber features for your campaign.